# The compact of an exterior derivative of a differential form $\omega$ is contained in the compact of $\omega$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is part of the proof of the Stokes' Theorem from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Let $M$ be an arbitrary smooth manifold with boundary, and consider an $(n-1)$-form $\omega$ that is compactly supported in the domain of a single positively oriented smooth chart $(U,\varphi)$. Then the definition yields
$$\int_M d\omega = \int_{H^n} (\varphi^{-1})^* d\omega.$$

For this to make sense, we need that $d\omega$ is also compactly supported in $U$. How can we prove this fact?

Comment: How do you define $d$?

Comment: Note that if $\omega$ is zero on an open set $U$, then $d \omega$ is also zero on said open set. This implies that $support(d\omega) \subseteq support(\omega)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar In the text, $d$ is defined as [in the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186351/intuitive-meaning-of-d2-0-for-differential-forms-de-rham-theory/2186359)

Comment: @DonThousand Do you mean something else? In the two answers there, one is only $d(df)$ and is only local, while the other one doesn't look like a definition.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah I misread. The way Lee defines $d$ is first defining it locally, and then stringing it together via a partition of unity. I'll find the page in the text once I'm off work.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$, proving $supp(d\omega)\subseteq supp(\omega)$ is equivalent to proving $M\setminus supp(\omega)\subseteq M\setminus supp(d\omega)$. Now take $p\in M\setminus supp(\omega)$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ such that $p\in V\subseteq M\setminus supp(\omega)$ since $supp(\omega)$ is closed by definition. You can always shrink $V$ and suppose that is contained in a local chart $(V_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ of $p$, and such chart always exists because $M$ is a manifold. This means that locally $$\omega=\omega_V dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_k}$$ and $\omega_V:V\to\mathbb{R}$ is the zero function because $V$ is not contained in the support of $\omega$. Now, $$\forall q\in V\quad (d\omega)_q=d(\omega_V)(q)\wedge dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_k}=0$$ And this is because $\omega_V$ is, in particular, a constant function. Thus, we have found a neighbourhood of $p$ on which $d\omega$ is zero which proves $p\in M\setminus supp(d\omega)$