# Why is the exterior product an antiderivation intuitively?

Tags: intuition, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I am attempting to motivate the form of the exterior derivative in the study of differential forms. In particular, I am trying to see why the following definition is compatible with Stokes' Theorem:

The exterior derivative is the unique map $d: \Omega^k(\mathbb R^n) \rightarrow 
\Omega^{k+1}(\mathbb R^n)$ such that

1. If $f \in \Omega^0(\mathbb R^n)$, then $df$ coincides with the derivative of $f$
2. $d$ is linear
3. $d^2 = 0$
4. If $\omega \in \Omega^k(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\eta \in \Omega^\ell(\mathbb R^n)$, then $d(\omega \wedge\eta) = d\omega \wedge \eta + (-1)^k \omega \wedge d\eta$ ($d$ is an antiderivation).

The first three properties already seem intuitive for me, in the light of Stokes' Theorem:

1. If $\int _M df = \int_{\partial M} f$ for a $1$-dimensional manifold $M$ and $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$, then Stokes' Theorem corresponds to the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals.
2. Every other iteration of the derivative is linear, so it makes sense for a generalization of the derivative to be linear.
3. The $d^2 = 0$ condition corresponds with the fact that the boundary of the boundary of a manifold always vanishes, as illustrated by Nox's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186351/intuitive-meaning-of-d2-0-for-differential-forms-de-rham-theory).

However, I am unable to find any kind of intuitive explanation for the antiderivation property of $d$. I could almost understand the idea if $d$ were an ordinary derivation (since regular derivatives do tend to be derivations), but where does the $(-1)^k$ factor come from?

(To clarify, I do not want to see this condition *derived* from an existing definition of the exterior derivative. I am attempting to see how the condition is *intuitive*, if we are looking to make Stokes' Theorem (as well as the 2D and 3D cases) true by choosing an extension of the derivative.)

Comment: d must filter through the product of k 1-forms..

Comment: @yngabl I'm not familiar with the term "filter" in this context. What does it mean?

Comment: I meant pass through

Comment: A remark on notations: $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R^n})$ is not the space of $k$-forms on $\mathbb{R^n}$, but the $k$th exterior power of $\mathbb{R^n}$. For instance, $\Lambda^0(\mathbb{R^n})$ is just $\mathbb{R}$, not smooth functions on $\mathbb{R^n}$. The classical notation for the space of $k$-forms is $\Omega^k(\mathbb{R^n})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you're fine with accepting that we should impose some sort of product rule in order to define $d$ (clearly product rule holds for functions, so we would like something similar to hold for higher order forms as well).

So, suppose the exterior derivative is such that for each integer $k,l\geq 0$, there exist $a_{kl},b_{kl}\in\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $k$-forms $\omega$ and $l$-forms $\eta$,
\begin{align}
d(\omega\wedge \eta)=a_{kl}\,d\omega\wedge\eta+ b_{kl}\,\omega\wedge d\eta.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Of course if $k=l=0$ then $a_{00}=b_{00}=1$. On the other hand, let us invoke the alternating nature of wedge products:
\begin{align}
d(\omega\wedge \eta)&=d\left[(-1)^{kl}\eta\wedge \omega\right]\\
&=(-1)^{kl}[a_{lk}\,d\eta\wedge \omega + b_{lk}\eta\wedge d\omega]\\
&=(-1)^{lk}[a_{lk}(-1)^{(l+1)k}\omega\wedge d\eta + b_{lk}(-1)^{l(k+1)}d\omega\wedge \eta]\\
&= (-1)^lb_{lk}\,d\omega\wedge \eta+ (-1)^{k}a_{lk}\,\omega\wedge d\eta\tag{$**$}
\end{align}
So, by comparing the coefficients in $(*)$ and $(**)$, we see that for all $k,l\geq 0$, we must have
\begin{align}
a_{kl}&= (-1)^lb_{lk}\quad \text{and}\quad b_{kl}=(-1)^ka_{lk}
\end{align}
By simple index manipulation you can see that these two conditions are equivalent. Therefore, the conditions on the coefficients are as follows:

- $a_{00}=1$.
- For all integers $k,l\geq 0$, $b_{kl}=(-1)^ka_{lk}$.

From these, we get $b_{00}=1$, so it is consistent with the product rule of functions. Notice that thus far, we have only derived the natural consistency condition arising purely because of how the wedge product behaves; and that's where the factor of $(-1)^k$ creeps in. The usual exterior derivative is obtained by setting $a_{kl}=1$ for all integers $k,l\geq 0$, so that $b_{kl}=(-1)^k$.

Comment: btw, more generally one can consider degree $r$ derivations (I believe that's the right terminology), meaning maps $\theta:\Omega^k\to \Omega^{k+r}$, where $r\in\Bbb{Z}$. Here, the product rule is $\theta(\alpha\wedge \beta)=\theta(\alpha)\wedge \beta+ (-1)^{kr}\alpha\wedge \theta(\beta)$, for $k$-forms $\alpha$, and $l$-forms $\beta$. The $(-1)^{kr}$ appears for an almost identical reason as I described above. (The exterior derivative has $r=1$, Lie derivative has $r=0$, interior product has $r=-1$).